# Old Passport not cancelled but i got new passport

Tags: indian-citizens, passport-renewals, lost-documents

I have lost my passport (date of issue 2013) so that i get it new passport (date of issue 2017). recently i got my old passport it is still have a validity of 2023. will that create any problem. i need to carry both the passports

Comment: You would surely have had to declare that your previous passport was lost when you applied for a replacement? Your first passport would have been cancelled when the renewal was issued. Why do you need to carry both?

Comment: Just get rid of your old passport to avoid potential issues.

Comment: He/She probably has a valid visa in it.

Comment: INSTANTLY report to the authorities that you have found it. THIS MINUTE.

Comment: @Fattie For what purpose? Cancelled passports can for obvious reasons usually not be 'reactivated'. In some countries OP may be required to return the passport to the authorities, either for withdrawal or voiding, but not necessarily. At least not INSTANTLY and THIS MINUTE. Indian passport authorities have a list of FAQs regarding lost passports and they do not mention that you have to inform anyone or return the passport if you find it again.

Comment: Simply for exactly the reasons outlined in the excellent answer below by some intelligent person.  OP "needs" to carry both passports.  What OP needs to do, to counteract their probable unfortunate actions, is INSTANTLY phone the authorities!

Comment: @Fattie If you read something in my answer indicating that there is an imminent need to contact any authorities, then please explain exactly what you are referring to so that I can clarify or rectify my answer. I see absolutely no need to contact any authorities here, they will not be able to do anything about the situation and as long as OP is not trying to use his old passport for anything, there is also nothing here to be worried about.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know why you think you need to carry your old lost-and-found passport. *Carrying* it is not a problem, but chances are high that you will run into problems if you try to *use* it for anything meaningful.

Interpol operates a 'Stolen and Lost Travel Documents' database, to which currently 174 countries deliver data. Your old passport is probably recorded in this database. Many countries check against this database on a regular basis when verifying foreign travel documents and if you try to use your old passport at a border crossing or during an in-land id check, chances are real that a red flag is raised and that it will be an issue that you are trying to use a document, which has been reported lost.